# How to add filters to a video in react-native? both on Android and iOS

Tags: react-native, mobile, video-processing

I have added filters to recorded videos using react-native-camera while recording.
But now I have to add filters after recording.
If anyone has the solution pls let me know.

There is a separate solution for Android, but can't find a solution that works cross-platform using react-native. Maybe we need to use third party APIs or something like that.

Comment: How about using a video-editor library like https://img.ly/video-sdk ?